# Как вернуться на определённую строку в коде? python

Tags: python

```
import time

while True:
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3")
    time.sleep(1)
    continue
```

Как вернуться на определённую строку кода и чтобы при этом не завершался цикл. Без def.

Comment: что конкретно вы имеете в виду? и что значит без def, без функций? или без слова 'def'?

Comment: Укажите пример: в каком месте программа должна возвращаться в другую часть кода. Если вы имеете в виду классическое `goto` - в python его нет вовсе, и помочь, не зная конкретной задачи, не представляется возможным.

Comment: Есть допустим текстовая игра. И мне нужно с одной части кода переключиться на другую часть(к примеру на 10 пунктов назад). Я знаю что нету goto в python. Но может есть что-то, что заменяет его в питоне?

Answer (score 2):

Аналог `goto`? Да действительно, встроенных инструментов, полностью реализующих функционал `goto`, нет (почему так сделано - отдельный вопрос). Однако есть огромное количество идиом, позволяющих частично или полностью эмулировать это.

Возможность "ветвления":

- [`if else statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement);
- [`try except statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement);
- выбор ключа в словаре;
- динамическое програмирование
  и т.п.

Возможность зацикливаться:

- [`for statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement);
- [`while statement`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement);
- встроенные высокоуровневые функции ([модуль `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#module-itertools)) 
  и т.п.

Есть и другие варианты, более специфичные. Также всегда есть возможность именовать одинаковые участки кода с помощью функций.

Если все-таки нужно написать именно аналог `goto`, то вот варианты:

- написать функцию, меняющую [байткод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) функции с `goto` (а конкретно, добавляющую где надо opcode `JUMP_ABSOLUTE`);
- написать свою [кодировку](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) с `goto`, ассоциированный декодер, зарегистрировать его, и писать в начале скрипта `#*- coding: my_goto_codec -*-`;
- написать функцию, наподобие [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), реализующую анализ инструкций вручную.

Как видите, гораздо проще пользоваться встроенными средствами, нежели городить трёхэтажные велосипеды с сомнительной полезностью. Лично я знаю только одну проблему, которую достаточно трудно решить подручными средствами в питоне - [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) из всех вложенных циклов в самое начало. Пожалуй, это единственное место, где `goto` был бы полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Питон высоко структурированный язык, *без возможности просто обозначить какую-то команду для прыжка в ее с другой части программы.*

Это сделано сознательно, чтобы такой возможности не было.

Когда вам это нужно, вам приходит подумать, если вам ясно, что от вашей программы ожидаете. Впервые стратегия, и только после ней тактика.

Например вы при каком-то условии хотите повторить часть с команды `print("2")`:

```
while True:
    print("1")
    time.sleep(1)
    something = True
    while something:
        print("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        if something_other:
            something = False   # Окончание внутреннего цикла
```

(Команда `continue` в вашем коде излишня.)